# pandas - getting first and last value from each day in a datetime dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of a month excluding Saturday and Sunday, which was logged every 1 minute.

```
                         v1         v2  
2017-04-03 09:15:00     35.7       35.4  
2017-04-03 09:16:00     28.7       28.5
      ...               ...        ...
2017-04-03 16:29:00     81.7       81.5
2017-04-03 16:30:00     82.7       82.6
      ...               ...        ...
2017-04-04 09:15:00     24.3       24.2  
2017-04-04 09:16:00     25.6       25.5
      ...               ...        ...
2017-04-04 16:29:00     67.0       67.2
2017-04-04 16:30:00     70.2       70.6
      ...               ...        ...
2017-04-28 09:15:00     31.7       31.4  
2017-04-28 09:16:00     31.5       31.0
      ...               ...        ...
2017-04-28 16:29:00     33.2       33.5
2017-04-28 16:30:00     33.0       33.7
```

how to resample dataframe to get 1st and last value from each day. The required data-frame :

```
                        v1         v2  
2017-04-03 09:15:00     35.7       35.4  
2017-04-03 16:30:00     82.7       82.6
2017-04-04 09:15:00     24.3       24.2  
2017-04-04 16:30:00     70.2       70.6
      ...               ...        ...
2017-04-28 09:15:00     31.7       31.4  
2017-04-28 16:30:00     33.0       33.7
```

Comment: hi, your times ending in 16:00 - can i assume you meant 09:16:00 and not 00:16:00? and will the same start and end times always exist or are there days where there won't be a print for 09:15:00 or 16:30:00?

Comment: @tbdees i just edited it. Also time varies each day, i just need to fetch the first and last value of each day

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
res = df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[[0, -1]])
res.index = res.index.droplevel(0)

print(res)

                       v1    v2
2017-04-03 09:15:00  35.7  35.4
2017-04-03 16:30:00  82.7  82.6
2017-04-04 09:15:00  24.3  24.2
2017-04-04 16:30:00  70.2  70.6
2017-04-28 09:15:00  31.7  31.4
2017-04-28 16:30:00  33.0  33.7
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Use df.groupby(column-name) to group the dataframe by date
2) use df.drop(..) to drop everything except first and last values in each group