# How do I find first and last value of each day in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas DataFrame like the below:

| Price | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 25149.570 | 2/5/2017 14:22 |
| 24799.680 | 2/5/2017 14:22 |
| 24799.680 | 2/5/2017 14:22 |
| 14570.000 | 2/5/2017 14:47 |
| 14570.001 | 2/5/2017 14:47 |
| 14570.001 | 2/5/2017 14:47 |
| 14570.000 | 2/5/2017 15:01 |
| 14570.001 | 2/5/2017 15:01 |
| 14570.001 | 2/5/2017 15:01 |
| 14600.000 | 2/6/2017 17:49 |
| 14600.000 | 2/6/2017 17:49 |
| 14800.000 | 2/6/2017 17:49 |
| 14600.000 | 2/6/2017 17:49 |
| 14600.000 | 2/6/2017 17:49 |
| 14600.000 | 2/6/2017 18:30 |
| 14600.000 | 2/6/2017 18:30 |
| 14800.000 | 2/6/2017 18:30 |
| 14600.000 | 2/6/2017 18:30 |
| 14600.000 | 2/6/2017 18:30 |

I want to find first and last value of each day based on Date column. The result can be like the below for the first day:

| Date | first | last |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/5/2017 | 25149.57 | 14570.001 |

I try to use this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52909610/pandas-getting-first-and-last-value-from-each-day-in-a-datetime-dataframe) solution but it does not work.
How do I find `First` and `Last Value` of each day (group by date)?

Comment: You have 3 values for the same datetime 2/5/2017 14:22. Why do you choose  25149.57 and not 24799.68? Same for 2/6/2017 18:30, why 14600.000 and not 14800.000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could convert "Date" column values to dates (without hours); then `groupby` it and use `first` and `last` to get the desired outcome:

```
out = df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))['Price'].agg(['first', 'last']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
         Date     first       last
0  02/05/2017  25149.57  14570.001
1  02/06/2017  14600.00  14600.000
```

Comment: Thanks @enke. How do i find and exclude daily outliers (find outliers in each day) ?

Comment: @bibiji how do you define an outlier?

Answer (score 4):

You have to ensure your dataframe is sorted by ascending `Date` (and maybe `Price`)

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=False)
out = df.sort_values(['Date', 'Price']).groupby(df['Date'].dt.date)['Price'] \
        .agg(['first', 'last']).reset_index()
print(out)

# Output
         Date     first       last
0  2017-02-05  24799.68  14570.001
1  2017-02-06  14600.00  14800.000
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pd.to_datetime` and [`dt.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) as a grouper for [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df2 = (df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date)
         ['Price'].agg(['first', 'last'])
       )
```

Output:

```
               first       last
Date                           
2017-02-05  25149.57  14570.001
2017-02-06  14600.00  14600.000
```

Comment: @bibiji you're welcome. Make sure the dates are sorted if using first/last

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use:

```py
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="D")).agg(["first", "last"])
```

##### Output

| Date | ('Price', 'first') | ('Price', 'last') |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-02-05 00:00:00 | 25149.6 | 14570 |
| 2017-02-06 00:00:00 | 14600 | 14600 |